# Iterate through element of array and then average

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have an array in Objective-C that stores basic mileage data. So each time I add to the array I add 4 elements (miles, litres, cost, MPG). If I save 10 entries I'll end up with 10 elements for say cost. How do I iterate through a specific element, assign them an index, add (total) them all up then divide by the total index number??
I've found plenty of info looping through basic arrays that just contain numbers and performing an average but I can't seem to get it to narrow down to a specific element? Should I create a new array with just the data that I need, then average that data, or can I work directly on the main array, which would be easier?

This will just work for a flat array if it were populated with just my cost data, it'll loop through and print to the console

```
for (NSString* string in arrayOfStrings ){
NSLog(@"%@", string);
}
```

So how would I drill down into this array say and achieve the same thing looking for my specific element of cost. I think I could work my way from there?

```
arrayOfStrings.cost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a class that has a cost property:

```
@interface MYCostObject : NSObject

@property double cost;

@end
```

You might think you can just loop over a collection of MYCostObjects:

```
MYCostObject* foo = [[MYCostObject alloc] init];
MYCostObject* bar = [foo copy];
foo.cost = 10.0;
bar.cost = 2.0;
NSArray* myArray = @[foo, bar];

double sum = 0.0;
for (MYCostObject* costObj in myArray)
{
    sum += costObj.cost;
}
double avg = sum/myArray.count;
```

But you could also just skip the enumeration in a loop and use a [collection operator](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/):

```
NSNumber* avg = [myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.cost"];
```

Comment: Excellent this did help greatly. I ended up using the collection operator for my original question. Thanks for you help and prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

you should post some code as I am unclear what you made an array *of*. Elements in an array just have an index, not a name. You might want an array of NSDictionaries. Then do something like:

```
int sum = 0;
int count = 0;
for(NSDictionary *entry in myArray) {
    NSNumber cost = [entry valueForKey:@"cost"];
    if(cost) {
        sum += [cost intValue];
        count++;
    }
}
int costAvg = sum / count;
```

Comment: I think you have just enlightened me. As you can imagine I've focused so much on the array I've lost track of what I was trying to do. I shall try your response as it makes sense. Looks like what I was after, you've managed to populate a dictionary from the array, then search for the cost key looping through, then divide by the number of loops. Well in my confused mind anyway. I shall try and get back if not get prepared for a copy of the code!! Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: you're welcome. You could also create a new class "MileageRecord" (or whatever) as your own subclass of NSObject and create an NSArray populated with MileageRecords, rather than NSDictionaries... depends how much you want to manipulate these entries. If there's a lot of logic on them, a class makes sense.